# Full ad blocking

Tags: applications, adblock-plus

I have installed and also properly configured AdBlock Plus. The problem is, that it doesn't remove all the ads. Sometimes I see ads at the bottom/top of the screen. Sometimes I see full screen ads and also there is an automatic popup after I unlock the screen lock(so not only in applications). I have installed also AirPush Ad detector.
Are there any better apps for this purpose.

Comment: May I suggest taking a look at my list of [Ad-Blocker apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker)? ;)

Comment: It's impossible to block all adds because no app can possibly know every source of ads that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go with this is having your device rooted and then install Adaway app. You can download from f-droid.org

Make sure you download the Adaway apk and not the F Droid app.

Once installed it modifies Android's hosts file and you won't see ads ever.

*+ Adaway is great, but it's power is dependent from the Hosts-Lists you use. I used to add EasyLists (Adblockplus is using this) at least, the links can be found here:
https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions*

Answer (score 0):

You can also try AdFree application from BigTinCan. You can download that at http://adfree.bigtincan.com/.

Comment: Why that? What does that app do better? Just throwing in a name does not really make a "good answer" ;) Maybe you could [edit] and improve it – e.g. describing what *AdFree* does and why you'd recommend it? Thanks!